# Natural sorting with Cloudant Search Index

Tags: sorting, lucene, cloudant

We have tested different analyzers on search Index but none of them gives a natural sorting order. All the analyzers except keyword analyzer tokenize the given input string before applying the sorting algorithm. With Keyword Analyzer we get ASCII sorting, but there is an issue. The lowercase strings are placed at the end of the list and all uppercase strings at the start. This is because, in ASCII, lower case letters are larger than the uppercase.

Example:
Input Strings: steve, John, Dave, george
After sorting: Dave, John, goerge, steve
Expected Output: Dave, george, John, steve

I wish to know if there is a way in cloudant where we can achieve natural/alphabetical sorting order irrespective of the case?

Comment: Could you create an index using a consistent casing of whatever the data value is?  E.g. index("lcname", doc.namefield.toLowerCase(),...)

Comment: i could index the data to lowercase. but if there are records with same data but different case then that sorting goes for toss.